# Chart.js: width and height of a pie chart not respected

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to create pie charts. I need each chart to be 76x76px. Unfortunately, the rendered chart is always a bit smaller than the size if the wrapping div and the canvas itself.

If you inspect the chart in the **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d6r00pv2/12/)**, you'll see what I mean: the `canvas` element has a fixed size but the chart itself doesn't fill it fully.

[image]

It's almost as if there was a top margin reserved for something that isn't there.

The code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="76" height="76"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [30, 70],
            backgroundColor: [
                'green',
                'gray'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
             enabled: false
        },
        events: []
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
}
```

Any ideas what I should do to make the pie chart fill the 76x76px canvas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The additional space is reserved for the `legend`, which is enabled by default under [`options.plugins.legend`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) namespace. Simply disable it and you should have the whole space for the chart:

```
legend: {
  display: false
}
```

A working example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [30, 70],
      backgroundColor: [
        'green',
        'gray'
      ],
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false  // <- the important part
      },
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* for demonstration purposes*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="76" height="76"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Jackpot! It felt kinda weird to be talking about a *"margin reserved for something that isn't there"* but there we go.

Comment: Well, you're right. You can report that behaviour here, if you want: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues ;)

Comment: Bravo!! Sir, you just saved my life!

Comment: Answer is good but doesn't resolve the problem with the last version, tooltip false and legend false

Comment: @Leandro I updated my answer to the latest Chart.js version, my approach is still working.

Comment: Set aspectRatio: 3 in the options, it will make it small too.

Comment: `borderWidth: 0` belongs in the options object. legend and tooltips are now implemented as plugins thus also inside the options object: `plugins: { tooltip: { enabled: false }, legend: { display: false } }`
Please update your answer to reflect the current version of chart.js.

Comment: Thank you @movAX13h for this suggestion. Disagree with you on `borderWidth`, agree with you on `tooltip` and `legend`. Updated my answer accordingly.